App crashes on iOS 17 and below on Xcode 16 with dyld`__abort_with_payload
While updating to Xcode 16, observed that the app runs all okay on all iOS 18 devices and sims but crashes for iOS 17 and below sims and devices.
This is the error:
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT dyld`__abort_with_payload

Also attaching the error in console when the app crashes.


Hi Sayalee, were you able to find the root cause of this crash?

@SagarD I have answered my question. Found a solution.

The reason for this crash was the name of the App target. App was named App
and that doesn't seem to sit well with Xcode 16 anymore.
There seems to be some naming conflict when calling the scheme App as well.
This Thread helped diagnose the issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/757397
